# I've arrived in Paris without ID, nobody checked my passport through whole process

Tags: airlines, deportation

I was flying to Bogota from Manchester with stop over in Paris. I've left my passport by Security in Manchester airport and nobody checked it by the gate and entering plane, guy on the gate also let me to the plane with 20 kg bag as I was running late. I've spent about £700 extra to get new flight to Colombia. I went through big embarrassment and lost two days of my holidays.

What recompense should get from Flybe?

Already put complaint but waiting from results.

I didn't show my passport to anyone at the airport, anyone...that means anyone using my boarding pass could enter the plane. I had a big 20 kg bag with me as hand luggage too as I was running late and was expected to pay but they didn't realize with this too. I was denied boarding in Paris to they deport me back to Manchester and I've been told I shouldn't be on this flight and airline will be charged 5000 euros for everything. I know it was my fault leaving my passport by Security but airline is responsible to check my ID to make sure it's me. My passport should be checked by the gate and entering the plane as far I know. I've paid another £500 pounds to get another new flight to Colombia plus internal flights there is airline responsibility to check my ID.

Comment: Why do you think you should get compensation from the airline? Many airlines don't check passports at the gate, especially if you've already shown it to them (or a kiosk) at check-in. You left your passport behind at security. That's unfortunate and mistakes happen, but I don't see why the airline is responsible.

Comment: Why did you need to spend 700 pounds to get a new flight? You were denied boarding in Paris? In Manchester?

Comment: Assuming FlyBe checked your passport when you checked in for the flight and it was valid for your travels, they have done their due diligence.  There are no rules that require them to double check your passport upon boarding. The responsibility lies 100% with you.

Comment: The person responsible is whoever left your passport behind in Manchester. Judging by your narrative, this doesn't appear to have been caused by any airline staff.

Comment: do you have travel insurance?

Comment: Yes but the think is I didn't show my passport to anyone at the airport, anyone...that means anyone using my boarding pass could enter the plane. I had a big 20 kg bag with me as hand luggage too as I was running late and was expected to pay but they didn't realize with this too. I was denied boarding in Paris to they deport me back to Manchester and I've been told I shouldn't be on this flight and airline will be charged 5000 euros for everything. I know it was my fault leaving my passport by security but airline is responsible to check my ID to make sure its me.

Comment: My passport should be checked by the gate and entering the plane as far I know. I've paid another 500 pounds to get another new flight to Colombia plus internal flights there is airline responsibility to check my id

Comment: Airline should check my passport at least once and regarding to police in France I shouldn't be on that flight and arrive in Paris, airline is getting charged already with deportation costs

Comment: But if they checked your ID at the gate and you didn't have your passport, you would still have missed the flight, right? Even if the airline is at fault, I think their only responsibility is towards France for letting you fly and not towards you.

Comment: I'd say you're lucky the airline isn't billing you for the 5000 euros. Yes, the airline should check your travel documents, but this is something they do to comply with immigration laws, not as a convenience to you. Airlines make it clear that passengers are responsible for all required travel documents. Ultimately, you're the one that made the mistake (and hey, mistakes happen). The airline simply failed to stop you.

Comment: I would go back to security and took my passport from security and make flight, regarding to your comments guys not showing ID at the airport especially with lots of terrorism going on is absolutely fine and its only my fault. Fair enough, flying without showing ID to anyone is ok...and its not airline responsibility just mine. thanks for all your comments

Comment: You want to pass the responsibility to the airlines when they in fact tolerated the extra weight and the fact that you had no ID on you? That's unethical mate, like its not enough that France is punishing them for your mistake

Comment: Surely yes, they should stop me by the gate and shouldn't let me enter the plane, I wouldn't go to emigrant centre and get deported and that would avoid me embarrassment. I'm sure its airline responsibility to check ID, I've read that in previous posts, I work myself at the airport and people from airlines told me they shouldn't let me to the plane without ID

Comment: Regarding to visa, yes airline is also responsible to checking visa, when I was flying to Vietnam, Emirates were checking my visa and without visa they wouldn't let me fly, simple

Comment: You have asked a question and are arguing with the answers because you don't like them. At the end of the day the airline DID check your ID and you left it behind by mistake. They allowed you to board because you had your boarding card. Someone needs to make their points in to an answer.

Comment: Can't you read it properly, nobody check my ID even once! 'Someone needs to make their points in to an answe'r  And surely its not you Terry, they didn't check my ID even once in the whole airport, even once!

Comment: At Manchester airport you have automatic boarding pass scanner gates, later you have security and first place where your ID is checked is gate and nobody checked my ID there where they were supposed to. That's why I argue with the answers

Comment: Hi Krystian. Please do not use the 'answers' space to have general discussions. if you have not done so, please have a look at [The Tour](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) which will tell you more about how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

> I was flying to Bogota from Manchester with stop over in Paris, I've
>   left my passport by security in Manchester airport and nobody checked
>   it by the gate and entering plane, guy on the gate also let me to the
>   plane with 20 kg bag as I was running late, I've spent about 700
>   pounds extra to get new flight to Colombia, I went through big
>   embarrassment and lost 2 days of my holidays, what recompensation I
>   should get from Flybe?

I'm not sure I understand your argument. Are you saying that since you misplaced your passport, you should not have been allowed to board (because they should check such things at the gate). Had you been denied boarding, you would not have run into problems at the destination?

I know in some airports, it is common to look at both the passport and the boarding pass; but it does not *have to be a passport*. The airline can ask for any form of government ID that is accepted for identification purposes.

*For example, citizens of GCC countries can travel among GCC member states simply by showing their national identification card - no passport is required.*

> I didn't show my passport to anyone at the airport, anyone...that
>   means anyone using my boarding pass could enter the plane. I had a big
>   20 kg bag with me as hand luggage too as I was running late and was
>   expected to pay but they didn't realize with this too. I was denied
>   boarding in Paris to they deport me back to Manchester and I've been
>   told I shouldn't be on this flight and airline will be charged 5000
>   euros for everything. I know it was my fault leaving my passport by
>   security but airline is responsible to check my ID to make sure its
>   me.

Checking the passport/documentation/id is the responsibility of:

1. The airline when checking you in. They need to ensure you have the proper documentation as the airline is normally fined (as you found out) if they carry passengers are that not eligible for entry at the destination. In fact, some airlines specifically have this disclaimer (which you must agree to) that they are not liable for any refunds if you are deemed ineligible at the port of entry.
2. The immigration officers at the airport (if applicable - for example, there are no exit formalities in the US). These officers are the **sole authoritative confirmation** of your immigration status/documents. They sometimes check your documents on departure, they always check your documents on entry - even if you are a citizen of the destination country or are otherwise similarly exempt from any visa/documentation requirements.

Throughout the rest of the journey - you are only responsible to carry government issued identification - and it does not need to be a passport. A resident card, or sometimes, even a driver's license is sufficient.

I flew from Amsterdam - Geneva - Malaga and no one asked for my passport. I only had to scan it at the kiosk to print my boarding passes.

Boarding passes once scanned for entry, cannot be used again.

Lets say someone made a copy of your boarding pass. They approach the gate before you, scan the boarding pass and board the aircraft. Now you arrive and try to scan your boarding pass - the gate will not open (in case its an automatic gate); as your boarding pass has already been utilized.

At this point, you will be asked to provide some identification.

> I've paid another 500 pounds to get another new flight to Colombia
>   plus internal flights

It it unfortunate that you were not stopped at your flight from Manchester to France and you had realized you had misplaced your passport. However, as you admit it was your fault, I am not sure what compensation you can expect from the airline.

Comment: +1 v nice.  Also...  Manchester has a  set of problems unto themselves, there are known vulnerabilities and they are always trying to fix them. You can cite http://icinspector.independent.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/An-inspection-of-border-control-at-Manchester-Airport.pdf in your answer if it's of any use so this answer can be 'canonical' for Manchester irregularities.